# How to check if all status codes are 200 in Mulesoft 4?

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Say for example, I created a flow for scatter-gather and I want to check if all endpoints are returning same result status code 200 or throw an error if not.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6j2M.png]

Comment: Do you want to throw error for each request or if one fails, other requests to be stopped aswel

Answer (score 0):

Configure the [Response Validator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-request-ref#http-response-validation) (General > Response > Response Validator) for each HTTP Request so only 200..299 responses are considered valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try block for every `HTTP request` on wrap whole scatter gather. If one fails, capture HTTP status code in `on error propogate` and log the results.

I suggest you wrap each request into try block, if you already have a `global error handler` defined, it should pick up status code 500 etc. Otherwise, capture response code into dataweave

[image]